# NavigationToolbar2Tk doesn't show button for plots editing

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

Is it possible to have the same navigation toolbar for tkinter (NavigationToolbar2Tk) and "normal" matpotlib window?

This [is the "standard" toolbar for matplolib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GyCD.png). Embedding in Tk [gives this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHHub.png). Basically, the button for plot editing disappears (the last one before the save button). Can I add it again?

Comment: This has nothing to do with embedding, this is about matplotlib's backends. What you call the standard toolbar is the one using the qt backend, when I use the tk backend, I don't have the edit plot button.

Comment: I have looked at matplotlib's source code, and this "plot editing button" is a specificity of the qt backend (`NavigationToolbar2QT` in matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py) so if you want it in tkinter you will have to code a similar edit dialog yourself.

Comment: Indeed it disappears when I use NavigationToolbar2TkAgg backend. I'll try to code my self as you suggested and I will share updates! Thanks!